# How to modify internal javascript code at run time?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to edit Javascript at run time if it is internal without having to reloading the page (and thus losing the modifications)?

Comment: I'm sure it is possible, but it will create code that is very difficult to maintain.  I would spend a little more time on the page architecture to choose a different way to meet the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You sure can!

In chrome:
Hit F12 (or ctrl+shift+j)
Hit the sources tab, use the file navigation to find the JS file you want to look at (or html file with js in it).

I believe you can right-click or do some fancy thing to edit it there, but I've always had much better luck copy/pasting the function with the code you want to modify into the console, making edits, and hitting enter.. that will re-define the function so next time it runs you get your 'custom' code instead of the original.

In the console you have access to all of the current variables, so you can just set them as you please too (including functions, which is why the above works)